# Updating table with arcpy make terminal hangs

Tags: arcpy, table, update

I am using this simple code to update a table on ArcMap:

```
# Setup
tableName = 'myTable'
tableInput = tableName +'.dbf'
fldName = 'myField'

# Updating
tableUpdate = arcpy.UpdateCursor(tableName)
i = 0
pct = int(919814 / 4) # to show % of advancement
for row in tableUpdate:
    if row.getValue('FID') <= 919814:
        if row.getValue('FID') == pct:
            print('25% done')
        if row.getValue('FID') == pct*2:
            print('50% done')
        if row.getValue('FID') == pct*3:
            print('75% done')
        if row.getValue('FID') == pct*4:
            print('100% done')
    #
    row.setValue(fldName,data[i])
    tableUpdate.updateRow(row)
    i = i + 1
else:
    break
```

From the code: (a) 919814 is the total number of rows to be updated; (b) 'break' is used because there are more rows inside the table (i.e., others I don't want to update); (c) 'data' is a list of integers of length 919815.

My problem:

The codes works during the first attempt and the update is made in a few minutes. However, when trying a second attempt (because the data are changed), the terminal run the code but hangs in (possibly) an infinite loop. I never see the '25% done' coming up.

Any idea why?

To solve it, I have to re-start ArcMap... and reload all my data from a csv file.

EDIT:
I've seen the '25% done' coming but after 30 mins, instead of 4mins... I do not understand why it takes longer at each second attempt (CPU usage and RAM usage look fine).

Comment: You should delete the cursor when it has run (with `del`), or better, use the new `arcpy.da` cursors in combination with a `with` statement. This closes the cursor automatically when it has browsed all rows.

Comment: Use `elif` instead of `if` when you check the FID value (conditions are exclusive here). Also, the `else` block is not aligned correctly, I suppose it's a copy/paste issue.

Comment: You could add a selection in the cursor to select only the rows with a `FID < 919814`, so the `else` block is not even necessary.